# How to solve binary image display problem PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, image, binary

I have a image in binary format stored in my database (SQL Server). I export these images by a backend procedure in `.PNG` format. The image exported successfully but when I am displaying the image in my webpage, it does not work. But if I open the image in Paint and save as `.PNG` format again, it works. Thank you in advance for your cooperation. Here is my code to display:

```
$image = 'D:\\myImage.PNG';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
echo '<img src="data:image/PNG;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
```

Comment: If the image was exported successfully, surely it would work properly and be displayed. Maybe the export process doesn't generate the image correctly. Have you tested that?

Comment: _“But if I open the image in Paint”_ - from _where_, exactly?

Comment: Thank your Dale. yes i tested the exported image,there is no error and the image view is ok. 'Paint' is the Windows default software we use sometimes for image editing. I just save as the exported image in that software in .PNG format again just for testing.

Comment: It would appear that paint must be correcting some information in the file when it re-saves it. Maybe there is something invalid which Paint can tolerate when it opens the file, but which causes the base64 generated by PHP from it to be invalid. Either that or you had a permissions error or something. I suggest comparing a copy of the raw file data before and after re-saving, to see if there's a difference.

Comment: I compared these two raw data, the only difference is image size. Generated image size is about 5 times lower than re-saves file

Comment: Sounds like it is producing something not entirely valid. I'd say your export process needs another look